# Write Sql compact database to disk using entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

How can you write a SQL compact entity to disk on demand, using an entity framework model?

We have an Entities object which inherits from `DbContext` and implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. This is how we interact with the SQL compact database. The constructor calls the `DbContext` constructor passing in a connection string:

```
// Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.
var entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder
{
    Provider = SqlCeProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName,
    ProviderConnectionString =
    String.Format("Data Source={0};Persist Security Info=False;Password=Password123;autoshrink threshold=100;flush interval=1", databaseLocation),
    Metadata = @"res://metadata files"
};
return entityBuilder.ToString();
```

I've attempted to disable autoshrink and write changes to disk after 1 second from the connection string, but it still appears that the database is not written to disk until the `DbContext` is disposed. Occasionally this happens sooner, but is unreliable when it occurs.

Comment: You need to wrap access to the database is a DbTransaction: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/05/sql-server-compact-code-snippet-of-week_21.html - if you use DbContext this seems to be possible: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.usetransaction(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Found the docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843